# How do I get both arabic and english text to show in a wordpress blog post?

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, arabic

I am trying to make a blog that has both arabic and english as primary languages.  I'm using unicode (UTF-8) as my character encoding but when I paste a chunk of arabic text into the editor, it comes out as all "?".  It shows up fine in the editor when I first paste it, but then after clicking update, it changes all the arabic text to junk. What can I do to keep the arabic text displaying correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a database charset problem.  Here are a few things you can try:

**Easiest**

Check in *Settings > Reading* that you've got encoding set to UTF-8.

**Easy**

Open up your wp-config.php and find this line:

```
 define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Change it to:

```
 define('DB_CHARSET', '');
```

**PITA**

Convert your database charset to UTF-8, as explained in [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets).